# No numpy, scipy, sympy and matplotlib minor-modes?

Tags: python, syntax-highlighting, minor-mode

Python scientific libs are immensily popular for the last decade or so. However googling and "melping" for its emacs minor-modes reveals nothing. Basically I need just syntax highlighting. Do you happen to know any efforts in this direction?

Comment: Uhm, Python Mode?  Isn't that enough?  None of these libraries add any special syntax that'd need to be highlighted…

Comment: Numpy, scipy, sympy and matplotlib are written in Python, if I'm not mistaken. Then python-mode would be good enough.

Comment: @(lunaryorn and ReneFrogertjuh): I'd like to see wither a given function is mine or belongs to the library.

Comment: You could always type `help(some_function)` into Python console. It's easy enough to figure out whether it's your own function or one you imported. Other options would be to use Ropes / Jedi to locate the source of a function.

Comment: @Adobe are your functions not namespaced? Are the `numpy` functions not namespaced? I can't see where the confusion would come from. In any case, I would highly suggest [anaconda-mode](https://github.com/proofit404/anaconda-mode), which is a superset of `jedi`.

Answer (score 0):

I know this question is old but for the record as of [2024-01-17] in my opinion I would recommend [emacs-jupyter](https://github.com/emacs-jupyter/jupyter) for your work with [ox-ipynb](https://github.com/jkitchin/ox-ipynb) for exporting as `.ipynb` for python scientific computing.

With `emacs-jupyter` + `ox-ipynb` you can create org files and share with non-Emacs people as jupyter notebooks, or maybe as PDFs with other native Emacs features.  For ordinary python files you can associate that buffer with a jupyter kernel for better completion and an interactive programming style coding experience, which is good for scientific computing.

Here are some alternatives:

[EIN](https://github.com/millejoh/emacs-ipython-notebook) used to be a good alternative if you want a more jupyter notebook style UI instead of the native `org-mode` UI.  However it is in sunset state since 2023, despite still having minor fixes, but I do NOT recommend it for this reason.

[code-cells](https://github.com/astoff/code-cells.el) might be good.  The UI seems to be more similar to Atom's `hydrogen` package.  It is less native because for hyper text it uses `markdown` instead of `org-mode`.  They claim to be safer when exporting as `ipynb` due to this design but I never tried it though so I'm not recommending.